# Extracting the right summary statistics from zero-inflated data sets (i.e. a sparse matrix where everything non-zero is a statistical outlier)

Tags: outliers, zero-inflation, frequency, sparse

I'm a consumer tech startup founder with rudimentary background in statistics. I need help in processing a large, sparse matrix.

I'm logging all actions users are undertaking in my app. I then produce a huge *frequency matrix* of the said actions, where type of actions form the columns, and various user IDs form the rows. Each cell contains the number of time the said user took the said action.

The data in this matrix is sparse (i.e. mostly 0's). At the moment, I'm looking at a 19200 x 203 matrix. My hope was to remove outliers from the said data, and then analyse which user actions occurred most frequently. This would help me find which actions might be correlated to app engagement.

But because of the sparseness of the matrix, anything with a non-zero value turns out to be a statistical outlier (i.e. the inter-quartile range for almost all columns in the matrix is 0, along with Q1 and Q2 being 0 too).

It seems all this frequency data is useless. Is there any transformation I can apply to the matrix in this scenario that allows me to carry out my desired analysis? To repeat, I originally wanted to find which actions occur most frequently (but while controlling for the effect of the rare over-zealous user, or bot).

---

Take a look at a representative sample of the data here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sVfeTkPBu7Nzg0v18510IJblW32D7NubvhHNOVrYdh4/edit?usp=sharing I've hidden unrelated columns. The first column is User IDs. The first row identifies types of actions (except the first cell, which contains a label for User IDs).

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve, but removing outliers is rarely justified or useful. If it's not a data recording error or something of the sort, you will be biasing your analyses if you exclude it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "statistical outlier."  You have merely misapplied a generic procedure for exploring data.  The zeros aren't outliers.  They aren't even data: they are simply place-holders for observations that could have occurred but did not.  Since you want to analyze the most frequent user actions, why not just identify them?  That's a very simple operation indeed.

Comment: @whuber♦: I've noticed that when actions are non-zero, there's a huge variance in them. Most non-zero frequencies lie between 5-10. Then there are rare users doing 200 of certain actions all by themselves. Since they're extremely rare, I felt they could be justifiably thought of as outliers, and be removed from the data since they totally fudge the mean.

Comment: But those seem to answer the very question you have!  If you throw out data about the most frequent actions, what's left that is useful?  Are you saying you aren't concerned about frequency but really about *numbers of unique users* engaging in activities?

Comment: @whuber♦: I have a separate *occurrence matrix* to analyze that sort of data, where instead of frequencies, I allot 0 and 1 depending on whether the action occurred or not. For this frequency analysis, my objective was to find which actions are highly engaging (i.e. most engaged users do them again and again and again). When 1 overzealous user carries out an action hundreds of times, it fudges the mean of the said action's frequency for engaged users.

Comment: Is it possible to show us mock-up data of the original data structure?

Comment: It doesn't "fudge" the mean, you have simply found out that the mean is not always a useful summary statistic. Try looking into zero-inflated distributions (ZIP/ZINBI).

Comment: @MichaelM: Certainly! I shared a viewable gdoc at the end of the question, have a look :-)

Comment: @FransRodenburg: thanks for increasing my knowledge (and curiosity). Now I understand the class of problem I'm dealing with. I'm reading up on zero-inflated models. Just to get a quick bird's-eye view, what are alt summary statistics in zero inflated models (which could be useful in a case like mine)?